# Add Language parameter in tweet using PHP

Tags: php, tweets

I want to add a language parameter. Suppose the user clicks on English, he will get tweets only in English. Right now I am using `en` by default, but I want support for multiple language

```
function twitter_class()
{
    $this->realNamePattern = '/\((.*?)\)/';

    $this->searchURL = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=';
}

$ch= curl_init($this->searchURL . urlencode($q));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

I want to get the language input from the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `searchURL` some parametrized string function:

```
$this->searchURL = function($language, $query) {
    $vars = array_map('urlencode', func_get_args() + array('', ''));        
    return vsprintf('http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=%s&q=%s', $vars);
}
```

When you invoke it, do it like this:

```
$ch = curl_init($this->searchURL($lang, $q));
```

Hope this is helpful.

---

If you don't have PHP 5.3, just write it as a standard class function:

```
class twitter_class
{
    ...

    function twitter_class()
    {
        $this->realNamePattern = '/\((.*?)\)/';
    }

    function searchURL($language, $query) {
        $vars = array_map('urlencode', array($language, $query));
        return vsprintf('http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=%s&q=%s', $vars);
    }

    ...

        $ch = curl_init($this->searchURL($lang, $q));
    ...
}
```

Comment: You need PHP 5.3 or higher to have that code to work. If you're below, create a named function out of the anonymous one.

Comment: :How it can be made as I am new in PHP?

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava: I edited the answer with some example code. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: :func_get_args(): Can't be used as a function parameter error

Answer (score 0):

```
function twitter_class($lang="en")
{
    $this->realNamePattern = '/\((.*?)\)/';

    $this->searchURL = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang='.$lang.'&q=';

}
```